# Is there a more concise way to count rows in a group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

here is a data table

[image]

to count the rows conditional on 'Age'=='young', group by Class, I use this piece of code

```
df.loc[(df['Age']=='young') & (df['Class'] == 'Yes'),'Class'].count()
df.loc[(df['Age']=='young') & (df['Class'] == 'No'),'Class'].count()
```

outputs

```
2
3
```

is there a concise way to get the number of rows (2 and 3)?

Comment: It's better to add a code or copy/paste example of your data, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
print(df.groupby('Class').size())
```

If you want only `'young'`:

```
print(df[df['Age'].eq('young')].groupby('Class').size())
```

Comment: Did you mean `print(df[df['Age']=='young'].groupby('Class').size())`?

Comment: @U9-Forward, nice one +1, this is easiest way with `.size`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `df.groupby(['Age','Class']).count()`. You'll get all counts by combinations of those values (not only Age==Young) but you can filter it out later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can count number for each class of age category:

```
df.groupby(['Age','Class'])['Class'].count()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are sufficient answers already been provided, However placing the example dataset here for the posterity to create & use the dataset for the sake of testing..

### Mimicking the Dataset:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': ['young','young','young','young','young'], 'Has_job':['False','False','True','True','False'], 'Own_house':['False','False','False','True','False',], \
...                    'Credit_rating': ['fair','Good','Good','fair','fair'], 'Class':['No','No','Yes','Yes','No']})
```

DataFrame:

```
>>> df
     Age Class Credit_rating Has_job Own_house
0  young    No          fair   False     False
1  young    No          Good   False     False
2  young   Yes          Good    True     False
3  young   Yes          fair    True      True
4  young    No          fair   False     False
```

1. Here Calling `.size()` will be the easiest way to get the Job as it returns `Series`

> ```
> >>> df.groupby(['Class']).size()
> Class
> No     3
> Yes    2
> dtype: int64
> ```

2. However, if you want return as a DataFrame and not a series then use below..

> ```
> >>> df.groupby(['Class']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
>   Class  counts
> 0    No       3
> 1   Yes       2
> ```

3. Or you can apply groupby as follows ..

> ```
> >>> df.groupby(['Class'])['Age'].count()
> Class
> No     3
> Yes    2
> Name: Age, dtype: int64
> ```

4. another way as suggested by @U9-Forward.

> ```
> >>> df.groupby(['Class'], as_index=False).size()
> Class
> No     3
> Yes    2
> dtype: int64
> ```

Comment: Regarding second example, you can also do `df.groupby(['Class'], as_index=False).size()`